# Прозрачность картинки в richTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Вставляю картинку из imageList в richTextBox1 (WinForm), но она имя изначально прозрачный фон там после вставки приобретает какой то серый, **я не могу понять где это отрегулировать**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему в Microsoft не любят людям упрощать простые веще?

Comment: Из-за проблем с прозрачностью всего подряд, я перешел с winforms на wpf. Там этой проблемы нет, вообще. Microsoft вам многое упростили, они сделали вам WPF, но вы не пользуетесь.

Comment: Но этот случай явно не упрощен, а организовывать взаимодействие WinForm и WPF еще то развлечение

Comment: Зачем взаимодействие, просто делаете проект в WPF, и вопрос решен. А так, в winforms нельзя делать прозрачные контролы. Но можно делать с таким же фоном как у подложки. Попробуйте задать картинке белый фон. Не самой картинке, а контролу, который в RTB ее содержит, это от него серый квадрат.

Comment: Проект уже работает в winforms, фон можно сделать белым но если потребуется копировать или использовать на другом фоне то ту и всё

Comment: В общем, в winforms нативно нет реальной прозрачности, есть только псевдо-прозрачность, когда контрол наследует цвет фона от подложки под ним. Если хотите реальной прозрачности, вам нужно реализовать свой рендер для контрола через GDI или DirectX.

Comment: И как он у меня умудрился белый фон richTextBox1 унаследовать серым,  хорошо а где есть примеры  GDI или DirectX

Comment: Сразу скажу, что WPF проще, чем то что вы спрашиваете. Примеры с GDI есть на Хабре. Пример с DirectX - WPF.

Comment: Ок я напишу.....